# Query a database of MongoDB from terminal: [MongoError]: failed to connect to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a web application and a database of MongoDB. Now, I just want to write scripts to query the database from terminal. I have written the following code.

```
const userModel = require('../models/Users');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CONN = 'mongodb://tie:<password>@178.62.87.72:27017/news'
const option = {
  socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 30000,
  // useNewUrlParser: true
};
mongoose.connect(CONN, option);
mongoose.connection.on('connected', async function () {
  console.log('Database connected: ' + CONN);
  try {
    let x = await userModel.user.find({ "_id": "5a95bbc0763e1f4bad37b864" }).lean()
    console.log(x)

    mongoose.connection.close()
    console.log("done");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
  console.log('Database disconnected:' + CONN);
});
```

Then, `node kpi.js` in the terminal returned an error:

```
events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [178.62.87.72:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 178.62.87.72:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16) {
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 178.62.87.72:27017'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/chengtie/Startup/PRODSERVER/From202005/funfun/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/chengtie/Startup/PRODSERVER/From202005/funfun/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/chengtie/Startup/PRODSERVER/From202005/funfun/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:189:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on NativeConnection instance at:
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/chengtie/Startup/PRODSERVER/From202005/funfun/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:325:19)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21) {
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [178.62.87.72:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 178.62.87.72:27017\n' +
    '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16) {\n' +
    "  name: 'MongoError',\n" +
    "  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 178.62.87.72:27017'\n" +
    '}]'
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Do I need to use for example MongoClient?

PS: I'm able to query the database by Robo 3T with the following settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Edit 1:** `ssh tie@178.62.87.72 -nNT -v -L 27014:localhost:27017` returned:

```
(base) Ties-MBP:kpi chengtie$ ssh tie@178.62.87.72 -nNT -v -L 27014:localhost:27017
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 178.62.87.72 [178.62.87.72] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 178.62.87.72:22 as 'tie'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:z8rrvKqvVmSxKFlCnb49HwUTQ/ABB9DUi9A3DUIpKtI
debug1: Host '178.62.87.72' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/chengtie/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:EL7hm5LvdVADZiv662nneDEeoLKy+etj8OT61eugu4Y
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:EL7hm5LvdVADZiv662nneDEeoLKy+etj8OT61eugu4Y
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/chengtie/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
tie@178.62.87.72's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 178.62.87.72 ([178.62.87.72]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:27014 forwarded to remote address localhost:27017
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 27014.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 27014.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
```

Comment: Do you have an `ssh tunnel` setup?

Comment: I'm able to use `ssh tie@178.62.87.72` then enter the password to connect to the server from my local linux, is it not enough?

Comment: Yes, i asked when you try to connect the Mongo instance if you have an SHH tunnel open on port 27017 on your local machine to transfer it to the server.

Comment: Do you mean I need to do `ssh tie@178.62.87.72` then run `node kpi.js` inside the server? I really want to be able to run `node kpi.js` from my local machine (like Robo 3T) without doing ssh explicitly.

Comment: No, i posted an answer with a more in depth explanation. the command you're currently using just connects to the server from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, and we also get a response from the server of `ECONNREFUSED` or in english connection refused. this can be caused from several different reasons. the most common is firewall / IP issue's (which is not your case as you manage to connect using `robo3T`).

If you look closely in the second image you post, the `ssh` tab you can see a box called `Use SSH Tunnel` marked. this is what you're missing to be able to connect from code.

Open a new terminal tab and run something like this:

```
ssh user@178.62.87.72 -L [LOCAL_PORT]:localhost:27017
```

Where `LOCAL_PORT` can be any open port on your localhost. This creates an open "tunnel" being your machines and the remote machine. and this is how Mongo can communicate with you.

Then change you're connection code to this:

```
const CONN = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:LOCAL_PORT'
```

You can keep using 27017 as your `LOCAL_PORT` but usually people have a running local Mongo process on that port.

Comment: I did `ssh tie@178.62.87.72 -L 27016:localhost:27017` in a terminal tab, put `const CONN = 'mongodb://tie:<password>@178.62.87.72:27016/news'` in `kpi.js`, and run `node kpi.js` in another terminal tab, it still returned me the `failed to connect to server` error.

Comment: If I do `ssh tie@178.62.87.72 -L 22:localhost:27017`, it returned me `bind [127.0.0.1]:22: Permission denied
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 22
Could not request local forwarding.`

Comment: I'm guessing you have a process listening to port `22`. try using something like `27014` that's a port that's not commonly used by any known program.

Comment: With `27014`, `node kpi.js` returned me the `failed to connect to server` error...

Comment: You need to add authentication like user,password / private key to the command. did you do any of the sort?

Comment: I put username and password in `const CONN...`, is it not enough?

Comment: No, the ssh command is unrelated to the mongo process from the code. it's the password /key to allow connection to the server.

Comment: I could do `ssh tie@178.62.87.72 -L 27014:localhost:27017` successfully and enter the server.

Comment: try running `ssh tie@178.62.87.72 -nNT -v -L 27014:localhost:27017`. what do the logs say?

Comment: I put the log in the OP.

Comment: It seems to be working, it could be that the pipe gets broken, try adding `-o ServerAliveInterval=60 ` to the command. it's a somewhat basic way to make sure the connection stays alive.

Comment: `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 tie@178.62.87.72 -nNT -v -L 27014:localhost:27017`

Comment: Just making sure, you are keeping the tunnel connection open in the terminal and running `node kpi.js` in a different tab?

Comment: Whats with the `/news` in `'mongodb://tie:<password>@178.62.87.72:27017/news'`? try removing that.

Comment: `news` is the name of the database, still got same error after removing that...

Comment: It seems that tie password is just a user for the server and not a user for the Mongo database. try `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27014` like `const CONN = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:21014/"`

Comment: Indeed, `const CONN = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27014/news'` works; username and password is not necessary here. Thank you...

Comment: Could you modify your answer (username and password is not necessary in the string of CONN) so that I could accept?